# Connection not close between SqlCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2016

I programmatically create a database then subsequently create a table in the database. The database is created, but not the table.

```
// Create Database
try
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connstr, sqlConn))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

// Create table
try
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable ("
                    + "ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + "MyProduct nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,"
                    + "MyDateTime datetime NOT NULL);"
                    + "", sqlConn))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

But I receive the error message saying my connection is not closed.

[image]

I tried repeatedly adding sqlConn.Close() to end of every {block} but still I get the same error. How can I properly close the connection after creating the database then reopen connection again to create table?

[EDIT]

Following the answers input, I have restructured my code that I'm sure wrapping property without duplicating Open().

```
    // Create Database
    try
        {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connstr, sqlConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        sqlConn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("(1)\n" + ex.ToString());
    }

// Create Table
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable ("
                            + "ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + "MyProduct nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,"
                            + "MyDateTime datetime NOT NULL);"
                            + "", sqlConn))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("(2)\n" + ex.ToString());
    }
```

Then I receive the error **There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database**. But when I look into SSMS, the table isn't there. I am very confused now.

[image]

Comment: It's better to show which is MyDatabase.cs:line 94.

Comment: Please stop writing `catch Exception` - it's a bad bad bad anti-pattern. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: In line with various answers telling you about using Connections in conjunction with Using blocks, I recommend reading about IDisposable and how Using blocks work with that interface. This will teach you why you don't need to call Close() on the Connection and other meaningful details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see that you close the connection for second query. You can wrap with using statement for ***SqlConnection***.

***FYI***: If you use using statement, you do not need to explicitly close the connection.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(...);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have restructured my code and wrap my cmd within conn with using statement, then I get a different error saying "MyTable already exist" caught by try block when creating the table. In SSMS, under Tables there clearly isn't MyTable. I tried deleting the entire database and start clean then I get the same error...

Comment: Could you ensure that table was not created in different database than you expected such as master database? Normally, you can check whether table exists or not before creating it `IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable')) BEGIN CREATE TABLE ... END`

Comment: As I said, you do not need `sqlConn.Close()` if you use using statement.

Comment: You are right. There was a Table in the master database. So I have explicitly type MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable instead of dbo.MyTable... I do not understand why the connection string already specify my database name, it still create it in master database instead of MyDatabase??

Comment: Could you show the connection string - *mask username and password*? Or, you can look at sample SQL Server Connection String [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: "Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master" this is what it stated in msdn tutorial without explanation so I thought it should be it.

Comment: Well, you will need to replace ***master*** with your database name. For example, `Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME`

Comment: I tried both `Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=True;database=MyDatabase` and `Server=localhost;database=MyDatabase` both gives me failed to login error. I use Windows Authentication for my database and I am already logged in...

Comment: Normally, I use  `Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabas‌​e;Integrated Security=SSPI;` for Windows Authentication for MS SQL.

Comment: Same Login Failed. I even tried this `Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=MyComputer\\MyUserName;Password = MyWindowsLoginPassword;` This is driving me nuts..

Comment: Could you try with () `Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=MyDatabas‌​e;Integrated Security=SSPI;`?

Comment: With () on localhost - (localhost), I get does not exist or not accessible error. I don't really get this why it worked originally with database=master but if =MyDatabase I get all these login failure.

Comment: How do you access database using SSMS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125217/discussion-between-win-and-kmc).

Answer (score 5):

When you go to create the table, you attempt to open the connection twice. The `cmd.Connection` property points to the same connection as `sqlConn`. Remove one of them.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable ("
                + "ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "MyProduct nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,"
                + "MyDateTime datetime NOT NULL);"
                + "", sqlConn))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    cmd.Connection.Open();  // don't need this...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx), this is expected behavior.

> InvalidOperationException
>
> Cannot open a connection without specifying a data source or server.
> or
> The connection is already open.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.May Be is Helpful.

```
public void NewClass()
{
    try
    {
        string query = "if exists(SELECT db_id('{0}'),'TEST') ";
        query += "begin ";
        query += "print 'All Ready Exists' ";
        query += "end ";
        query += "else ";
        query += "begin ";
        query += "create database TEST ";
        query += "end ";

        lblno.Text = query+"<br>";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        int ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Cancel(); cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();

        string table = "if exists (select OBJECT_ID('test')) begin ";
        table += "print 'all ready' end ";
        table += "else begin ";
        table += "CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,MyProduct nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,MyDateTime datetime NOT NULL) ";
        table += "end ";

        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-0R1BJNQ\\HARDIKPATEL;Initial Catalog=" + dbnm + ";Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(table, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Cancel(); cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();

    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = err.ToString();
    }
}
```